# svg stroke text doesn't work inside foreignObject

Tags: css, svg

Bellow the code, I want add stoke to the text , Howerver it doesn't work.

```
// the html code
<article class="module article-3">
   <svg width="100%" height="100%">
     <foreignObject  width="100%" height="100%">
         <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">something words.....</div>
     </foreignObject>
   </svg>
 </article>

// the css code
.article-3 text {
     stroke-width: 6px;
     stroke: black;
}
```

Has some method can stoke text and make sure text can auto line feed?(excepted using javascript)
I have tested using css property: text-shadow , however, text-shadow will performance not well.

Comment: @RobertLongson I know this ,howerver , if I remove foreignObject the text can not auto line feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the option of using `-webkit-text-stroke`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke

It works on most browsers. But it is not standardised, and may disappear in the future.
It's up to you whether you want to risk it.

```css
.article-3 div {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px red;
}
```

```html
<article class="module article-3">
   <svg width="100%" height="100%">
     <foreignObject  width="100%" height="100%">
         <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">something words.....</div>
     </foreignObject>
   </svg>
</article>
```